# Can Model View Update be used with Uno Platform?

Tags: elmish-wpf, model-view-update

I am looking into using the Model View Update pattern in Uno Platform.
Just like this project:
https://github.com/unoplatform/Elmish.Uno

However, Elmish.Uno is troubled:
A: 3 years since last maintainance
B: from the page and docs, it is unclear to me how this project works with Uno, and if it is cross platform.

Are there alternatives to Elmish.Uno, which also provide Model View Update?

Answer (score 0):

I am the lead maintainer of Elmish.WPF.  As I recall (because it is hard to check right now on my phone), the Elmish.Uno repository to which you linked is a fork of Elmish.WPF version 2.  GitHub user xperiandri has recently forked Elmish.WPF version 3 and (to the best of my knowledge) made it work for Uno.  See https://github.com/xperiandri/Elmish.Uno.  My primary focus with Elmish.WPF right now is significantly improving the API and releasing this improvement as version 4.  After that, I will spend more time helping xperiandri with his Uno fork of Elmish.WPF.  If you were able to help xperiandri with his Uno fork, I expect that help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Tyson for your quick response, and your most authoritive even.
I am wondering, and it's hard for me to grasp this after a LOT of research,
but does https://github.com/xperiandri/Elmish.Uno run on Android, iOS and web?
It's hard for me to find how to actually build Fable applications :)

Comment: I don't know. I recommend asking that question in an issue of that GitHub repository.